# Why when i Enabling Comet on Glassfish it fails in my situation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, comet, grizzly, cometd

I want to enable comet on glassfish especially cometd, Bayeux Protocol, implementation.

Following this article: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/ghgxn/index.html.

when using this command:

```
asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-1.http.comet-support-enabled="true"
```

I get this error: `Command set failed.`

what puzzles me more is what does this line means:

```
Substitute the name of the protocol for http-1.
```

I tried to replace `http-1` with `bayeux` but didn't work either.

EDIT: Following @perissf advice, i assembled [this war file](http://www.4shared.com/file/pkQ-rTsH/hello_comet.html), it deploys fine on glassfish, i'm using Firebug Console, when i click the button on index.jsp nothing gets outputed. any idea?

Comment: If you want to use [cometD](http://cometd.org), forget about the linked article and rely solely on cometD's tutorials / documentation. This means adding the servlet in web.xml, and the jetty continuation API libraries to your app. It will work in GlassFish without need to enabling comet support.

Comment: The protocol name for the listener you're enabling comet on is defined in the domain.xml.  If you're just using the default listener configuration, then this value should be http-listener-1.  If you want to enable comet over ssl, then the value would be http-listener-2.  Again these are defaults.  You can confirm the actual names on the admin gui.